# Use ping output to create a CSV

Tags: function, powershell, csv, ping

I have written following code to use ping command to ping multiple computers, I would like to capture following values it:

1. Reply from  / Request timed out etc.
2. Actual IP Address of the remote host

This function is working fine however, if I am trying to get its returned values to a CSV I am unable to do so.

```
# Declaration of the function name and expected parameters
Function Ping-Check{
[cmdletbinding()]
PARAM (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
    HelpMessage='Enter the name of the remote host.')]
[String]$ObjCompName
)
Begin{
# Setup the Process startup info
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "ping.exe"
$pinfo.Arguments = " -a " + $ObjCompName + " -n 2"
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
}
Process{
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
# Redirect the Output
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
}
End{
Write-Output "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Output "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Output "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Test-Connection`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135266) cmdlet available in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) which returns an object array with properties you can use. If you wan't to stick with your attempt, be aware that you have to *parse* the output yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @Martin.  I am aware of Test-Connection cmdlet.  However, I would like to capture the actual response / error thrown by Ping command so that I can determine the exact cause of no response and take further actions.

Comment: try assigning the results of test-connection to a variable, then pipe the variable to gm.  You'll see lots more properties than the ones displayed.  Maybe that includes the information you need.

Comment: <code>      Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer '<computername>' failed: No such host is known
At line:1 char:11
+ $result = Test-Connection -ComputerName <computername> -Count 2
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (<computername>:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCo 
   mmand <code>